# python sort and select older values based on their datetime

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services

I am working on finding old duplicated running instances in my AWS account.

So far i have the following JSON data available where I have duplicate instances listed.

```
[
    {
        "InstanceName": "example-instance-0",
        "InstanceId": "i-0966108",
        "InstanceLaunchTime": "2019-06-20 19:10:50+00:00"
    },
    {
        "InstanceName": "example-instance-1",
        "InstanceId": "i-0d83ecc",
        "InstanceLaunchTime": "2019-06-20 22:27:10+00:00"
    },
    {
        "InstanceName": "example-instance-0",
        "InstanceId": "i-0268215",
        "InstanceLaunchTime": "2019-04-19 14:25:11+00:00"
    },
    {
        "InstanceName": "example-instance-1",
        "InstanceId": "i-0a9b614",
        "InstanceLaunchTime": "2019-06-19 21:57:50+00:00"
    }
]
```

From here I wanted to exclude latest instance by date and time and print all other instances.

I am able to do this using `pandas` dataframe. But not able to figure out without using pandas. Is there any way to accomplish this?

The output i am looking:

```
example-instance-0,i-0268215,2019-04-19,14:25:11
example-instance-1,i-0a9b614,2019-06-19,21:57:50
```

I apologize, i am still beginner in python, and seeking help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that should do the trick,  note I have not formatted the output as string you are looking looking at output list you can format and get way you need

```
inputs = [
{
    "InstanceName": "example-instance-0",
    "InstanceId": "i-0966108",
    "InstanceLaunchTime": "2019-06-20 19:10:50+00:00"
},
{
    "InstanceName": "example-instance-1",
    "InstanceId": "i-0d83ecc",
    "InstanceLaunchTime": "2019-06-20 22:27:10+00:00"
},
{
    "InstanceName": "example-instance-0",
    "InstanceId": "i-0268215",
    "InstanceLaunchTime": "2019-04-19 14:25:11+00:00"
},
{
    "InstanceName": "example-instance-1",
    "InstanceId": "i-0a9b614",
    "InstanceLaunchTime": "2019-06-19 21:57:50+00:00"
}
]

outputs = []
keys = []
for ip in reversed(inputs) :
    if ip["InstanceName"] not in keys :
        outputs.append([ip["InstanceName"], ip["InstanceId"],     ip["InstanceLaunchTime"]])
        keys.append(ip["InstanceName"])
print (outputs)
```

You will get output

```
>>> [['example-instance-1', 'i-0a9b614', '2019-06-19 21:57:50+00:00'], ['example-instance-0', 'i-0268215', '2019-04-19 14:25:11+00:00']]
```

Comment: this is selecting the latest entries but my requirement is to drop latest one and prepare a list of older entries. You are almost close i think.

Comment: this is selecting older entries, but order may be reversed change out.append to output.insert(0, [ip[...)   this shoud give the output

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [{'InstanceId': 'i-0966108', 'InstanceName': 'example-instance-0', 'InstanceLaunchTime': '2019-06-20 19:10:50+00:00'}, {'InstanceId': 'i-0d83ecc', 'InstanceName': 'example-instance-1', 'InstanceLaunchTime': '2019-06-20 22:27:10+00:00'}, {'InstanceId': 'i-0268215', 'InstanceName': 'example-instance-0', 'InstanceLaunchTime': '2019-04-19 14:25:11+00:00'}, {'InstanceId': 'i-0a9b614', 'InstanceName': 'example-instance-1', 'InstanceLaunchTime': '2019-06-19 21:57:50+00:00'}]
result = []
for _, v in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x["InstanceName"],x["InstanceLaunchTime"])), lambda x: x["InstanceName"]):
    result.extend(list(v)[-1:])  #Exclude latest item
pprint(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'InstanceId': 'i-0268215',
  'InstanceLaunchTime': '2019-04-19 14:25:11+00:00',
  'InstanceName': 'example-instance-0'},
 {'InstanceId': 'i-0a9b614',
  'InstanceLaunchTime': '2019-06-19 21:57:50+00:00',
  'InstanceName': 'example-instance-1'}]
```

Comment: this is not working properly if the date is same and time has difference like "2019-06-20 19:12:50+00:00" and "2019-06-20 19:12:20+00:00". It should drop the time with 19:12:50. Correct?

Comment: try : `result.extend(sorted(list(v), key=lambda x: x["InstanceLaunchTime"])[-1:])  #Exclude latest item`

Comment: or `for _, v in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x["InstanceName"],x["InstanceLaunchTime"])), lambda x: x["InstanceName"]):`

Comment: in any case can we remove the timezone and separate date and time and validate entries ? For me it is selecting the latest one if date is same.

Answer (score 0):

first sort based on `timestamps` and then remove the duplicates.Try below code.

```
lst1=[
    {
        "InstanceName": "example-instance-0",
        "InstanceId": "i-0966108",
        "InstanceLaunchTime": "2019-06-20 19:10:50+00:00"
    },
    {
        "InstanceName": "example-instance-1",
        "InstanceId": "i-0d83ecc",
        "InstanceLaunchTime": "2019-06-20 22:27:10+00:00"
    },
    {
        "InstanceName": "example-instance-0",
        "InstanceId": "i-0268215",
        "InstanceLaunchTime": "2019-04-19 14:25:11+00:00"
    },
    {
        "InstanceName": "example-instance-1",
        "InstanceId": "i-0a9b614",
        "InstanceLaunchTime": "2019-06-19 21:57:50+00:00"
    }
]
#Sort here based on timestamps using lamda function
lst1=sorted(lst1, key = lambda i: i['InstanceLaunchTime'].split(' ')[1])
res_list = []

seen = set()
res_list = []
for d in lst1:
    if d['InstanceName'] not in seen:
        seen.add(d['InstanceName']) 
        res_list.append(d)
print(res_list)
```